# resizing rect but keep text at same pos

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a rect that i resize with text on it.
The text is drawn on top of that rect with DT_CENTER, I want the text to be able to stay in its same position but only print the parts that would be seen where the rect is ontop.

At the moment my text just prints at its right spot but shows when the rect is not even under the text.

This is set in WM_TIMER i add 10 to i everytime timer called
this it is all drawn in WM_PAINT

This is when the rect slides from left to right:

```
    if (i <= m_sWndSize.cx)
    {
        m_rcCurrent = { 0, 0,  i,  m_sWndSize.cy };
        m_rcCurrentText = { 0, 0,  i,  m_sWndSize.cy };
    }
```

Comment: How can your code be **c** and **c++** at the same time?

Comment: its not i added the c tag because c++ is so much c, and this is kinda to do with math. i removed the c tag.

Comment: Create a clip region from the rectangle using `CreateRectRgnIndirect` and install it using `SelectClipRgn` before you draw the text.

Comment: I gave that ago but not really sure how to use it, my text just shows up when its not over the rect.

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks @JonathanPotter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out with what Jonathan Potter said.

With the use of `CreateRectRgnIndirect` and `SelectClipRgn`

Thanks